# Argument must be a string or a number issue, Not 'Type' - Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn, data-science

**Update:**
So i have been looking into the issue, the problem is with scikit-multiflow datastream. in last quarter of code `stream_clf.partial_fit(X,y, classes=stream.target_values)` here the class valuefor stream.target_values should a number or string, but the method is returning (dtype). When i print or loop stream.target_values i get this:
[image]

I have tried to do conversion etc. but still of no use. can someone please help here ?

**Initial Problem**

I am running a code (took inspiration from [here](https://github.com/hassanmehmud/d3-discriminative-drift-detector-concept-drift/blob/master/D3.py)). It works perfectly alright when used vanilla python environment.

But if i run this code after certain modification in Apache Spark using Pyspark , i get the following error

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'type'`

I have tried every possibile way to trace the issue but everything looks alright. The error arises from the last line of the code where hoefding tree is called for prediction. It expects an ndarray and the type of X variable is also ndarray. I am not sure what is trigerring the issue. Can some one please help or direct me to right trace?

**complete stack of error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-1310132c88db> in <module>
     30         D3_win.addInstance(X,y)
     31         xx = np.array(X,dtype='float64')
---> 32         y_hat = stream_clf.predict(xx)
     33 
     34 

~/conceptDrift/projectTest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/skmultiflow/trees/hoeffding_tree.py in predict(self, X)
   1068         r, _ = get_dimensions(X)
   1069         predictions = []
-> 1070         y_proba = self.predict_proba(X)
   1071         for i in range(r):
   1072             index = np.argmax(y_proba[i])

~/conceptDrift/projectTest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/skmultiflow/trees/hoeffding_tree.py in predict_proba(self, X)
   1099                     votes = normalize_values_in_dict(votes, inplace=False)
   1100                 if self.classes is not None:
-> 1101                     y_proba = np.zeros(int(max(self.classes)) + 1)
   1102                 else:
   1103                     y_proba = np.zeros(int(max(votes.keys())) + 1)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'type'
```

**Code**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark as ps
import warnings
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score as AUC
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skmultiflow.trees.hoeffding_tree import HoeffdingTree
from skmultiflow.data.data_stream import DataStream
import time
def drift_detector(S,T,threshold = 0.75):
    T = pd.DataFrame(T)
    #print(T)
    S = pd.DataFrame(S)
    # Give slack variable in_target which is 1 for old and 0 for new
    T['in_target'] = 0 # in target set
    S['in_target'] = 1 # in source set

    # Combine source and target with new slack variable
    ST = pd.concat( [T, S], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
    labels = ST['in_target'].values
    ST = ST.drop('in_target', axis=1).values
    # You can use any classifier for this step. We advise it to be a simple one as we want to see whether source
    # and target differ not to classify them.
    clf = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
    predictions = np.zeros(labels.shape)
    # Divide ST into two equal chunks
    # Train LR on a chunk and classify the other chunk
    # Calculate AUC for original labels (in_target) and predicted ones
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True)
    for train_idx, test_idx in skf.split(ST, labels):
        X_train, X_test = ST[train_idx], ST[test_idx]
        y_train, y_test = labels[train_idx], labels[test_idx]
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        probs = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
        predictions[test_idx] = probs
    auc_score = AUC(labels, predictions)
    print(auc_score)
    # Signal drift if AUC is larger than the threshold
    if auc_score > threshold:
        return True
    else:
        return False
class D3():
    def __init__(self, w, rho, dim, auc):
        self.size = int(w*(1+rho))
        self.win_data = np.zeros((self.size,dim))
        self.win_label = np.zeros(self.size)
        self.w = w
        self.rho = rho
        self.dim = dim
        self.auc = auc
        self.drift_count = 0
        self.window_index = 0
    def addInstance(self,X,y):
        if(self.isEmpty()):
            self.win_data[self.window_index] = X
            self.win_label[self.window_index] = y
            self.window_index = self.window_index + 1
        else:
            print("Error: Buffer is full!")
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.window_index < self.size
    def driftCheck(self):
        if drift_detector(self.win_data[:self.w], self.win_data[self.w:self.size], auc): #returns true if drift is detected
            self.window_index = int(self.w * self.rho)
            self.win_data = np.roll(self.win_data, -1*self.w, axis=0)
            self.win_label = np.roll(self.win_label, -1*self.w, axis=0)
            self.drift_count = self.drift_count + 1
            return True
        else:
            self.window_index = self.w
            self.win_data = np.roll(self.win_data, -1*(int(self.w*self.rho)), axis=0)
            self.win_label =np.roll(self.win_label, -1*(int(self.w*self.rho)), axis=0)
            return False
    def getCurrentData(self):
        return self.win_data[:self.window_index]
    def getCurrentLabels(self):
        return self.win_label[:self.window_index]

def select_data(x):
    x = "/user/hadoop1/tellus/sea_1.csv"
    peopleDF = spark.read.csv(x, header= True)
    df = peopleDF.toPandas()
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    df.iloc[:,0:df.shape[1]-1] = scaler.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,0:df.shape[1]-1])
    return df
def check_true(y,y_hat):
    if(y==y_hat):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
df = select_data("/user/hadoop1/tellus/sea_1.csv")
stream = DataStream(df)
stream.prepare_for_use()
stream_clf = HoeffdingTree()
w = int(2000)
rho = float(0.4)
auc = float(0.60)


# In[ ]:


D3_win = D3(w,rho,stream.n_features,auc)
stream_acc = []
stream_record = []
stream_true= 0

i=0
start = time.time()
X,y = stream.next_sample(int(w*rho))
stream_clf.partial_fit(X,y, classes=stream.target_values)
while(stream.has_more_samples()):
    X,y = stream.next_sample()
    if D3_win.isEmpty():
        D3_win.addInstance(X,y)
        y_hat = stream_clf.predict(X)
```

Comment: It seems that the error is coming from the line stream_clf.predict(xx). Please check the xx variable and ensure that it contains numeric, string or byte values only.

Comment: i checked it. not sure whats going on. works fine in vanilla environment

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis i checked again. X array contains values of dtype=objects. I tried converted them to float as well. but the is still persistent

Comment: Ok try gradually by excluding parts of your dataset until your are 100% sure that no bad values exist in your data

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis I just updated the question, can you please look may be you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with select_data() function, data type of variables was being changed during the execution. This issue is fixed now.

Comment: Good, you see I could not help anyway :)

Comment: You did though, :D forced me to look again.